# Click on a <button> tag

Tags: c#, click, buttonclick, invokemember

I want to click on a  tag with C#.

I use `element.InvokeMember("click")` but it doesn't make a click. When button is with tags `<input type="button">` than `InvokeMember("click")` is working, but with `<button>` tag, click doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

[Related forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c15b8fab-767c-4d00-9164-ce519149a4ee), which had no solution.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "input" in declaration use "button" then put  tag in your code, like this :

```
 var buttonControls = (
            from HtmlElement element 
            in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button") 
            select element
        ).ToList();
```

Comment: I got right element, it is <button id="someid" type="submit"> </button>   and I want now to click. I have no problem to navigate the right element. @EhsanKeramat

Comment: so, check your declaration code in custom code that you make, this code work.